# Adding own JS Module to TYPO3 object

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typo3-8.x

I've successfully injected my own requireJS Module in Backend.

How can I add my object to the TYPO3 object? I thought its done by the line "TYPO3.ContentAnalyze = ContentAnalyze;"

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    /**
     * The main ContentAnalyze object
     *
     * @exports TYPO3/CMS/DreipcCa/ContentAnalyze
     */
    var ContentAnalyze = {
    };



    /**
     * Initialize
     */
    ContentAnalyze.initialize = function() {
        console.info('Extension dreipc_ca loaded');
    };



    $(ContentAnalyze.initialize);
    TYPO3.ContentAnalyze = ContentAnalyze;
    return ContentAnalyze;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `top.TYPO3` can solve your issue.

May I ask you what you want to achieve? "Polluting" the global namespace is considered bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Didn't know that. I thought I dont want to add another object to window. 
I want to have some functions avaiable in Backend. These are needed by extra buttons in docHeader in all Content Elements.

Comment: Going with proper event handling should also solve the issue. Regarding the window object: I think there is some misunderstanding. What I meant was `top.TYPO3.ContentAnalyze`, the window object is already aware of `TYPO3`.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help. I'll see.

Comment: you were right. There is no need to attach anything to window or TYPO3 object. Thanks for the hint